# Is it possible to fix or declare a type for a cell in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, types

I know that in VBA, we can do

```
Cells(4, 2).Value = 100      'the cell is an integer
Cells(4, 2).Value = True     'the cell is Boolean
Cells(4, 2).Value = "abc"    'the cell is Text
```

Is it possible to fix or declare the type of a cell, for instance, let `Cells(4,2)` accept only Boolean, such that assigning an `Integer` or `Text` to `Cells(4, 2)` gives an error?

Comment: FYI - tried Data Validation, didn't work.

Comment: I mainly focus on VBA... Just want to make sure that it is not possible to `fix` or `declare` that in VBA.

Comment: You wanted to raise an error while using VBA or when typing in Excel?

Comment: @Jean-Francois - Doesn't work in VBA.  If you set up validation in VBA (say, and integer between 1 and 10000) and then say Cells(1,1)="abc", you won't get any complaints.

Comment: @RoyTruelove: Aha, now I understand what you mean. You can *set* the validation from VBA, but not *use* it from VBA, i.e. can still set the cell value to be anything from VBA. You're right.

Comment: @RoyTruelove: You can capture that using Worksheet_Change Event as well ;)

Comment: @SoftTimur: My question is then: *why do you want to do this?* Are you trying to protect yourself from yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[EDIT** This solution can be implemented from VBA, but it cannot be used from VBA, i.e. can't prevent VBA user from setting cell value to be anything (though not manually in Excel sheet). Not sure what the OP actually wants.**]**

Use Data Validation.

You can do it via VBA:

```
Range("A1").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="TRUE,FALSE"
```

or manually: (In Excel 2003: Data > Validation...)

[image]

Now you can enter only boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE` in cell A1. If you try to enter something else, e.g. a number:

[image]

Using data validation, you can also restrict the cell to accept only numbers, only integers, text of a certain length, basically anything. For example, to accept only text and *not* numbers, you would use Allow: Custom, Formula: `=NOT(ISNUMBER(A1))`.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: Regarding your edit: Worksheet_Change Event can trap that as well :)

Answer (score 4):

If you actually want the cell type to be specified, you can't. All cells in VBA contain variant data types, to the best of my knowledge.

If you mean the data type of the variant, then sure, you can do it one way or another. Here's a suggestion, it's a little quick and dirty but it works. You'll need to put it in your worksheet code module. Note that it doesn't test if your bool range, int range, whatever intersect, that could cause you some problems if they do.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo handler

    Dim cell As Range, _
        boolRng As Range, _
        intRng As Range

    Set boolRng = Union(Sheet1.Range("A1:B2"), Sheet1.Range("E:E"))
    Set intRng = Union(Sheet1.Range("B7:K12"), Sheet1.Range("M:M"))

    If Not Intersect(Target, boolRng) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, boolRng)
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                cell.Value = CBool(cell.Value)
            End If
        Next cell
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, intRng) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, intRng)
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                cell.Value = CInt(cell.Value)
            End If
        Next cell
    End If

    Exit Sub

handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 13 'Type mismatch, raised when cint/cbool/c*** fails
            cell.Value = ""
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End Select

End Sub
```

Edit: I note you want to raise an error if the value is assigned incorrectly, you can do that in the error handling section. Instead of

```
Cell.value = ""
Resume Next
```

You could use

```
Err.Raise ISuggestAnEnumForErrorNumbers, "Sheet1.Worksheet_Change(Event)", "Attempted to assign wrong type to cell."
```

Comment: I wouldn't have done all the logic this way but that's a good stab (and +1)

Comment: Nice effort, but you're reinventing the wheel! Data validation is already implemented in Excel.

Comment: Oops, I may have spoken too soon, depending on what the OP actually wants (which is not entirely clear).

Answer (score 4):

I second JFC's suggestion on using Data Validation.

To test it, place this code in a module (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .Validation.Delete
        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="TRUE,FALSE"
        .Value = "SID"
    End With
End Sub
```

and this in the relevant sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        On Error Resume Next
        If Not Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Cells.Count < 1 Then
            Dim currentValidation As Excel.Validation
            Set currentValidation = Target.Validation

            If currentValidation.Type = xlValidateList Then
                '~~> I am using INSTR. If you want you can split it using "," as delim 
                '~~> and check for the value.
                If Not InStr(1, currentValidation.Formula1, Target.Value, vbTextCompare) Then
                    MsgBox "Incorrect Value"
                    Target.ClearContents
                End If
            End If
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Now try running the `Sub Sample()` in the module.

Comment: +1 LOL. Damn Kool. Is then any VBA question for which you do not know the answer? :D

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar: Yeah! Unfortunately there are plenty of them :( LOL.

Comment: In effect you're doing a sideways enforcement of the data validation... This will only work for the "List" data validation, however. Still, not bad.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: It works for other type of validation as well :)

Comment: I guess that with some effort you could emulate the enforcement of other types of data validation as well... (e.g. list whose source is a range...) +1 for the fact that this ties together the advantages of both approaches.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: Yes it can work with other type of validation as well. In fact, I am so inspired with this question that I am actually writing a blog post on this :) "It cannot be used from VBA" was too much of a temptation for me LOL ;)